# problem with a series

Tags: analysis

I have a problem with series
$\sum_{k=1}^ \infty k*(\frac{1}{2})^{k+2}$
How can I solve it?

Comment: Try talking to her

Comment: Consistent with the duplicate @Winther found, note that $$k\left(\frac 12\right)^{k+2} =  \left(\frac 12\right)^2 \cdot k\cdot \left(\frac 12\right)^k$$  In other words, you have the sum $$\frac 14\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left(\frac 12\right)^k$$

Comment: @Winther  thanks!